# Bad decrypt using openssl, however plaintext looks mostly fine

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, openssl

I'm having a problem with a decryption routine, namely that it seems to work most of the way, but not all the way.

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
//EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(&ctx, 0);

if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
{
    ERROR0(_logger, "Decryption error: " + getSslErrors());
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    break;
}

encryptedData = encryptedData.mid(16);
char *input = encryptedData.data();
int len = encryptedData.size();
int pLen = len;
int fLen = 0;
uchar* plaintext = (uchar*)malloc(pLen + 16);

if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(&ctx, plaintext, &pLen, (uchar*)input, len))
{
    ERROR0(_logger, "Decryption error: " + getSslErrors());
    free(plaintext);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    break;
}
```

At this point, if I take a peek at the already decrypted plaintext, it looks perfectly fine, except the last few bytes are missing... However, if we continue:

```
if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(&ctx, plaintext+pLen, &fLen))
{
    ERROR0(_logger, "Decryption error: " + getSslErrors());
    free(plaintext);
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);
    break;
}
```

At this point, I get a bad decrypt error. With nothing else to clue me in on what that error actually means. What could it mean?

Comment: Its hard to say since pieces of the program are missing; and the security paramters like key and iv are missing. If you think `decrypt` is OK, then the problem is with `encrypt`, or the subsequent {serialization|de-serialization} of the encrypted data. But I gotta say, this looks suspicious: `encryptedData = encryptedData.mid(16)` considering its CBC mode. There should be a lot more code to support the seek 16 bytes into the stream. By the way, where is `mid` coming from? I don't believe its from `std::string`.

Comment: It's a QByteArray, not a string. And I don't do the encryption on my side, I just decrypt data that gets sent over the internet. As for the iv and key, they're obviously correct, because I get everything but the last few bytes decrypted, it's just EVP_DecryptFinal_ex that doesn't seem to be working. I'm seeking 16 bytes into the stream because the first 16 bytes are the IV.

Comment: The exact error is `1996453100:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:516`

Comment: Perhaps you should use hard coded data and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Include the way you load the paramters, like key and iv, into your `QByteArray`, and the way you convert it to bytes. I don't usually ask for them, but too much is missing for me to hazard a guess.

Comment: So, after some more digging, it turns out that there is an issue with the padding. Because at the point where it errors, plaintext contains `"...-----SSH PRIVAT"` and ctx.final contains `"E KEY-----\n\0\0\0\0\0"`So obviously the key and the IV are both correct, it's just the padding that's wrong. It's those nul-bytes that are making OpenSSL error out. And while it's not nice, I know that I'm decrypting private keys, so I know what to expect, so I can reconstruct despite the errors, and despite how hacky it is.

Comment: *"... it turns out that there is an issue with the padding..."* - That's not padding. `"...-----SSH PRIVAT"` and `"E KEY-----\n\0\0\0\0\0"` - That's a malformed pre-encapsulation header. It looks like a buffer that's been purposefully back-filled with a default character value. Something C++ would do... There's a bug somewhere in the handling of the key. You should probably hunt it down.